# Xpages ACL to view

Tags: view, xpages, acl

Is there a way to set the documents visible in the view for only specific users? I have a namesPicker which takes all the users from the names.nsf database, and I want to allow the creator of the document to put a protection on the document. The creator of the document would select which user/s from the names.nsf database can see the document in the view, and open it. Is there a way to do this?

I am thinking that with the namesPicker I only get a string value of the names of the users, and how can I put then the document protected for those specific users?

I have already created the document, the only thing missing is this protection issue, which I think will not be easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setReaders(true)` for your document item

```js
var doc = document1.getDocument(true);
var item:NotesItem = doc.replaceItemValue("Readers", namesPickerValue);
item.setReaders(true);
```

This gives your item the "readers" property. Only people or groups listed in this field are allowed to read the document.

`namesPickerValue` can be String or an Array of Strings or a Vector or a List. Make sure the names are canonically like "*CN=Knut Herrmann/O=Leonso*" or as a common name like "*Knut Herrmann*" (not recommended). The format "*Knut Herrmann/Leonso*" doesn't work.

Here is a sample code for converting names listed in field "inputText1" to canonical format and to write into Readers item as readers field:

```js
var doc = document1.getDocument(true);
var value = getComponent("inputText1").getValue();
var array = [];
if (typeof value === "string") {
    var name = session.createName(value);
    array.push(name.getCanonical());
    name.recycle();
} else {
    var it:java.util.Iterator = value.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        var name = session.createName(it.next());
        array.push(name.getCanonical());
        name.recycle();
    }               
}
var item:NotesItem = doc.replaceItemValue("Readers", array);
item.setReaders(true);
```

Comment: If I use an inputField to store for example 3 usernames selected from namesPicker, can I use getComponent("inputField1").getValue and asign it to var namesPickerResult?

Comment: Yes, you can use `getComponent("inputField1").getValue()` for namesPickerValue. But, make sure the names are canonicalized.

Comment: What you mean by document item? To add another field with id Readers? Do I have to bound it?

Comment: I am getting the following error: Unknown member 'iterator' in Java class 'java.lang.String'

Comment: I saw that if I only set one user in the inputText1 I get this error.

Comment: I think that my problem is that I do not understand what is an item. I found something about NotesItem [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/b8d165cec5afe71c8525642e007687da?OpenDocument)

Comment: An item is a field in a Notes document.

Comment: So I have to create another field in my form and add this value to it? Where do I put the code? I tried in the querySaveDocument but doesn't work.

Comment: I am creating a code for you and will post it in some minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61873/discussion-between-noname-and-knut-herrmann).

Comment: Just a side note, you'll probably want to add another Readers item that gives admins access (use a group name or [acl role]). That way, admins can also see documents. If you access these documents programmatically, you will also need to add the signer of the database.

Comment: Yea that would be interesting... But I don't know how to accomplish that. I am thinking of adding by default a list of users, the admins, to the inputText.

Comment: You can do both. You can put all names/groups/roles into one field or you can split it to different readers fields. For read access Notes/Domino looks into all readers (and author) fields.